# Transparency group and decoration markings

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

How can I set the transparency so that the arrow belongs to the same `transparency group` as the path?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{%
    > = stealth,
    arrow over path/.style = {%
      decoration = {%
        markings,
        mark = at position .5 with {\arrow {>};}
      },
      postaction = decorate
    }
  }
  \draw[arrow over path, semitransparent] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't *think* this can be done easily within a path (but I could be wrong). Surrounding the `\draw` command with `\begin{scope}[opacity=.5,transparency group]` and `\end{scope}` should work (provided the back-end driver supports it).

Comment: ...and remove the `semitransparent` key from the `\draw` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As requested, the comment becomes an answer:

This cannot be done currently within a path as far as I can tell. But, a `transparency group` can be used (provided the back-end driver supports it). Note, that the transparency is specified in the surrounding `scope` *not* the path:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{%
    > = stealth,
        arrow over path/.style = {%
        decoration = {%
        markings,
        mark = at position .5 with {\arrow {>};}
        },
        postaction = decorate
    }
}
\begin{scope}[opacity=.5, transparency group]
    \draw [arrow over path] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]