# tikz stroke opacity of line intersections

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, draw

Consider the following simple example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.2cm,y=.2cm]
  \draw[ultra thick,opacity=0.5] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
  \draw[ultra thick,opacity=0.5] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.2cm,y=.2cm]
  \draw[ultra thick,opacity=0.5] (0,-1) -- (0,1) -- (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: stroke opacity]

What is interesting about this is of course the intersection of the lines at `(0,0)`. It looks more dark in the left picture, which is presumably caused by the fact that TikZ actually draws the paths one-after-the-other, which yields a higher total opacity (combining both lines). In the second, right picture, the lines are all drawn in one go, which meas that the crossing will only be drawn once, after which the opacity will be applied.

This is all good, but my question is: Is there any way I can make sure that TikZ draws intersections of paths "correctly" (as in, double-layers them) also when drawing a single path in one go (that is, make the intersection in the right picture look like the one in the left picture), or is this a futile exercise?

Comment: For what it's worth, the vocabulary for this idea in the pgf/tikz manual is `transparency groups`.

Comment: I guess yes. You can modify `show path construction` so that it draws all subpath separately.

Comment: But then wouldn't the corners be dark too?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: they will, and the segments are not joined. Allthough, with `line cap=round` the latter wouldn't show.

Comment: I would be really surprised if this can be done. I'm quite sure that single path can't be placed in different isolated groups.

Comment: Yes marsupilam is right `transparency groups` works. See: [Transparency group and decoration markings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128758/124842). So for you: `\begin{scope}[opacity=.5, transparency group]
  \draw[ultra thick] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
  \draw[ultra thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
  \end{scope}` is fine.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Would you like to write up an answer, or close as duplicate?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think we should close the question as duplicat.